# Smack DeliveryReceipt not working

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am trying to implement DeliveryReceipt using smack(version 4.1.7) library. After reading so many posts, which are saying the same thing what I have implemented but still not working.

Is [XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html): Message Delivery Receipts supported by Ejabberd 16.04 and is there any configuration to enable it?

Can you please help me with letting me know what did I missed here to make it working? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

```
    ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceipt.ELEMENT, DeliveryReceipt.NAMESPACE, new DeliveryReceipt.Provider());
    ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(DeliveryReceiptRequest.ELEMENT, new DeliveryReceiptRequest().getNamespace(), new    DeliveryReceiptRequest.Provider());

    DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();

    deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
            Log.d("XMPP Receipt Received", "From: " + fromJid + " TO: " + toJid);
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you have added the request to your sent message?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: `deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();` does automaticatlly I think? If not please let me know

Comment: yes, if you defined the message type, it should. But it´s also possible that it´s a bug. Have you defined the message type?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: I didn't define any message type, doc. says automatically it takes 'normal' and 'chat' message type

Comment: usually it should....but just define a message type and look if it´s working. I faced some bugs in smack, so it´s possible that it is one. I would try the following: define message type and add the request to the message. If this works, but the autoAddDelieveryReceiptRequest not, than I guess it´s a bug.

Comment: another thing what I see from your code, looks a little bit suspicious to me. Your Log is tagged with `"XMPP Receipt Received"` ....maybe a stupid question, but...are you sure you set the correct filter to logcat? For simplicity, a Tag is usually set to "TAG","SMACK" or some other one-word.......not a whole sentence...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: Yes it sets the correct Tag, I have so many tags like this only :). It would be really helpful if you can provide any sample code to set message type and working code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129240/discussion-between-gathole-and-opiatefuchs).

Comment: Any solve for this issue?

Comment: @radityagumay: Didn't find any solution so far... still working on this

Comment: Actually, i was play with deliveredreceipt, and it was successfully. but i dont know later, listener not invoke anymore. I had talk with server ejabber team, they has change ejabber version. maybe that cause the problem. but, they not revert the version.